# How to face outliers on a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, landsat, outlier

I am trying to calculate a Soil Moisture Index using the procedure of this article: ["Estimation and evaluation of high spatial resolution surface soil moisture"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016706120303074). My final SMI's range is not 0 - 1 as it should. Instead it is -0.04 - 1.17. I tried to figure out what those pixels below 0 and above 1 represent. As we see from Image 5 & Image 6 those pixels represent Barren Land and Vegetation accordingly. What I thought, it is appropriate to do is to extract those pixels from my SMI raster. Image 7 shows SMI with the correct range, after extracting those pixels. I understand that, following article's procedure, SMI range must not be less than 0 and greater than 1.

- Could it mean that I am "unlucky" and my raster has a lot of outliers which cause this problem?
- Also, can my approach on Image 7 be considered as correct, or due to removal of enough pixels is it wrong?

Article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016706120303074

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you link to the article you are referring to?

Comment: Here it is, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016706120303074 @lambertj

Comment: It certainly is possible to have values outside of your range, unless it's a normalized equation. There is probably a reason for it. You may want to look at the 'raw' pixel values where you have anomalies and see if their reflectance values are high/low for some reason. It's also good to know how many of these values you have and how they're distributed

Comment: I guess, looking at raw pixel values means to investigate bands' values which I used for my project. In this case I used Band 4,5 and 10 of a Landsat Collection 1 Level 1 image. I think that, they represent Digital Numbers and not reflectance. Should I convert them to reflectance values and check about anomalies? is this what you mean? Thank you! @GeoMonkey

Comment: @Chris You should transform to reflectance values if the equation requires it. My assumption is yes. DN values and reflectance values are not equitable. You can directly download surface reflectance data.

Comment: It is a normalized equation because SMI=(LSTMax-LST)/(LSTmax-LSTmin). I installed Collection 2 Level 2 data but I came up with the same range problem..any ideas ? @GeoMonkey